# What is the usage of `FilteredRelation()` objects in Django ORM (Django 2.X)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I've seen Django 2.0 consists of `FilteredRelation` object in queryset. What is the usage of newly introduced `FilteredRelation`?

#### What I've looked into?

I observed [Django 2.0 Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects) but I could not understand idea behind this `FilteredRelation` object.

I looked into following code. But I didn't get it.

```
>>> from django.db.models import FilteredRelation, Q
>>> Restaurant.objects.annotate(
...    pizzas_vegetarian=FilteredRelation(
...        'pizzas', condition=Q(pizzas__vegetarian=True),
...    ),
... ).filter(pizzas_vegetarian__name__icontains='mozzarella')
```

#### Main Question

> Show now my question is that what is usage of `FilteredRelation` and when to use in your `QuerySet`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the documentation itself self-explanatory.

You could achieve the same result in,
**Method-1**

```
from django.db.models import FilteredRelation, Q

result_1 = Restaurant.objects.annotate(pizzas_vegetarian=FilteredRelation('pizzas', condition=Q(pizzas__vegetarian=True), ), ).filter(
    pizzas_vegetarian__name__icontains='mozzarella')
```

**Method-2**

```
result_2 = Restaurant.objects.filter(pizzas__vegetarian=True, pizzas__name__icontains='mozzarella')
```

You will get better performance with **Method-1** since the filtering in the **WHERE** clause of the first queryset will only operate on vegetarian pizzas.

---

### UPDATE

The [**Django #29555**](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29555) ticket has more information regarding the usage and performance.
The **`FilteredRelation()`** not only improves performance but also creates
        correct results when aggregating with multiple `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: Does both of the query returns same results?

Comment: Yes. But, you can't use `FilteredRelation` always because it has some restrictions. (specified on ***FilteredRelation doesn’t support*** section of the doc)

Comment: Should I use F('field_name') within condition

Comment: Nop, because an  [**`F()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) object represents the value of a model field or annotated column.