# How to perform the join on multiple fields in django queryset?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

Here is my models :

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    picture_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='PictureID', primary_key=True)
    gold_item =models.ForeignKey(GoldItem,db_column="GoldItemID",related_name="pictures",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gold_item_branch = models.ForeignKey(GoldItemBranch, db_column="GoldItemBranchID", related_name="pictures", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.CharField(db_column='Code', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)


class GoldItemBranch(models.Model):
    gold_item_branch_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='GoldItemBranchID', primary_key=True)
    gold_item_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='GoldItemID')
    gold_item_branch_name = models.CharField(db_column='GoldItemBranchName', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
```

I need to perform the join operation on multiple columns in above models. The columns are gold_item_id and gold_item_branch_id

I wrote the SQL Query :

```
select * from Pictures 
join GoldItemBranches on Pictures.GoldItemID = GoldItemBranches.GoldItemID and Pictures.GoldItemBranchID = GoldItemBranches.GoldItemBranchID
```

[image]

How I can do the same query in Django queryset ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into django's [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) lookup.

Example:

`Picture.objects.select_related('gold_item__gold_item_id').filter(gold_item_branch=gold_item_id)`

Comment: Worth to mention: without select_related you also can access related fields in lazy mode

Comment: @DINOLIN It won't give the same result as I mentioned in the SQL query, !, thank you

Comment: This is in not correct -- it would not join on multiple fields

Answer (score 0):

You can try;

```
ids_list = GoldItemBranch.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
results = Picture.objects.filter(gold_item__id__in = ids_list).select_related('gold_item_branch')
```

If you want to see which query is actually executed:

```
results.query
```

There's another method to run the raw SQL using django. So, in your case, it would be like:

```
raw_results = Picture.objects.raw('''select * from Pictures 
                       join GoldItemBranches 
                       on Pictures.GoldItemID = GoldItemBranches.GoldItemID 
                       and Pictures.GoldItemBranchID = GoldItemBranches.GoldItemBranchID''')
```

And iterate over this raw query result

```
for raw_result in raw_results:
    print(raw_result)
```

For more on performing raw SQL queries: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Thank you, After all my research about the multi column join , I found that it better to go with the raw SQL. I tried to fix the query in the django queryset , but I couldn't get any useful solutions.  
These are also the same issues : https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19385 ,
https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/8iqexz/django_orm_join_base_on_two_columns_question/

Comment: The `FilteredRelation` solution worked for me! Check more here: https://www.py4u.net/discuss/240050

Comment: @johnecon link giving 404, what is the solution?

Comment: Hey @ShikharTyagi, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391181/what-is-the-usage-of-filteredrelation-objects-in-django-orm-django-2-x

Answer (score 0):

To perform a multiple-column join, use [FilteredRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects).